# Can anyone tell what kind or even which airplane this is?

Tags: airliner, aircraft-identification, cabin-design

As stated in [this post on the Dutch Police website](https://www.politie.nl/nieuws/2018/juni/12/nieuwe-foto%E2%80%99s-van-taghi-en-razzouki.html) ([Google Translate English version](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.politie.nl%2Fnieuws%2F2018%2Fjuni%2F12%2Fnieuwe-foto%25E2%2580%2599s-van-taghi-en-razzouki.html&edit-text=)) this morning (12th june 2018), they are looking for all available information concerning the image below. All help is appreciated!

[image: The aircraft in question]

**[Update]** Additional information: the picture was presumably made on the 16th of January 2018 at 20:57 local time. They are looking for any information about airplane type, carrier or maybe even flight number.

Comment: Why do they want to know?   I don't see anything untowards there.

Comment: @Cees Would you contact Dutch police with all info gathered here?

Comment: @Bentoy13 since Cees did not respond and the information found seems legit, i've contacted the Dutch police and shared the information found so far

Comment: @CrossRoads Presumably, they found the photo on somebody's phone and want to know where the person was on that day. That could be in relation to a criminal inquiry, or a missing person case, for example. I edited the question to link the Google translation of the Dutch Police page.

Comment: Post it to airliners.net and they will be all over it.

Comment: Yes sorry for the late reply, thanks for all the help. I contacted the Dutch Police and notified them of this thread! Excellent work by Bentoy123!

Comment: @CrossRoads Here is an [English article](https://nltimes.nl/2018/06/12/police-release-photos-criminals-wanted-assassination-investigations) with some background.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may be an A318 with cabine plan like [this one for Avianca](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Avianca/Avianca_Airbus_A318-100.php):

[image: cabine plan A318-100 avianca]

My guesses are:

- the emergency light line stops around row 6, with the (red?) curtains around row 4.
- the seats arrangement is approximately 3 rows of business class then economy class.
- best guess would be 2x3 seats per row, with central screen every three row.
- cockpit door is slightly not centered to the left

So it can fit with this type of plane.

Sorry,  I can't guess the company. The curtains seems red, but the cabine does not fit with AirFrance (and Hop) neither British Airways.

**EDIT**

- According to the video posted by @Florian in comments, Avianca is a good guess for the company.
- Following the comment of @jean, and considering the shadows on the seats, it may be taken during daylight (in flight or on the ground) but for sure not during night.

Comment: Also: I'm not sure at all about the seats but they look like old Aircelle seats (sth like 15 years ago) AirFrance was using in their planes. Not put this guess in my answer, I doubt we can get sth from it.

Comment: Looks like this Avianca cabin interior https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8ic-XnWUb8

Comment: @Florian You're right, it seems to be like this one. Yet I am not sure as this type of plane is owned by several other companies for which I haven't found the cabine interior plan. But I can't find a detail in your videao that don't match the picture.

Comment: I looked up from the other carriers that are listed in WP:EN some cabin interior pictures on google image search, they all look totally different.

Comment: @Florian Thank you for this info, post updated. Next step is to look on flightradar24 or similar website, if anyone has an account and enough time for this.

Comment: I tried but since the time stamp doesn’t have a time zone it’s rather difficult to tell which one it could have been

Comment: Yes, same pattern and curtains of an avianca, just guess it's a A319 based in seat configuration

Comment: @jean A319 at Avianca has 5 rows between exit door and curtains, and I think there are fewer rows here.

Comment: @Bentoy13 Looking again in the police site (better resolution) I can see the emergency exit. One question: is this day light from the windows? I ask because the time stamp

Comment: @jean I think you're right, I didn't notice the shadows. Interior light can't lighten the side of the seats. Another element to take into account is the fact that the top ligths appear saturated on the ceiling of the cabin, so the daylight may be not so strong. I think it's hard to guess the actual hour, the only thing we can be confident enough with is that the picture must be taken not during night (all people there seem awake, I can't see any sleep mask).